# The Abelian Finite Group Category has not arbitrary products.

Tags: category-theory

I want to prove that. I know an object of that category is: $\mathbb{Z}_{p_{1}}\times...\times\mathbb{Z}_{p_{n}}$, where $p_{i}$ are primes. But I'm stuck there.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply say that if $A,B$ are two finite abelian groups, then $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ is a finite set.

However, the functor $A\mapsto\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\operatorname{Hom}(A,\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ does not always take a finite group to a finite set. Hence, it cannot be represented by a finite group. (An object representing this functor is by definition the product $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Can you put me an example of this product is not always a finite set?

Comment: Take $A=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, so this is isomorphic to $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.